# Open chrome process with not decoded URL

Tags: c#

```
ContextMenu context = new ContextMenu();
MenuItem menuItem1 = new MenuItem();
menuItem1.Header = $"Homeplus Search with '{text.Text}'";
menuItems.Add(menuItem1);
menuItem1.Click += delegate
                {
                    string Encode = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(text.Text.Replace(' ', '+'));
                    Process process = new Process();
                    process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
                    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "http://www.homeplus.co.kr/app.search.HeaderSearch.ghs?comm=usr.header.search.basic4&search_query="
                        + Encode + " --new-window";
}
```

Finally, it must be execute commend "chrome.exe "http://www.homeplus.co.kr/app.search.HeaderSearch.ghs?comm=usr.header.search.basic4&search_query=%ea%b0%80%ec%98%88%ea%b7%a0%ec%9d%bc%ea%b0%802000%ec%9b%90 --new-window"

but exactly execute "chrome.exe [http://www.homeplus.co.kr/app.search.HeaderSearch.ghs?comm=usr.header.search.basic4&search_query=가예균일가2000원](http://www.homeplus.co.kr/app.search.HeaderSearch.ghs?comm=usr.header.search.basic4&search_query=%EA%B0%80%EC%98%88%EA%B7%A0%EC%9D%BC%EA%B0%802000%EC%9B%90)" then finally it fail to search with decoded keyword.

I want to execute search with encoded keyword but I don`t know how to make it.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: @AngryHacker Above url query "%ea%b0%80%ec%98%88%ea%b7%a0%ec%9d%bc%ea%b0%802000%ec%9b%90" must be decoded when open homeplus site then search with keyword "가예균일가2000원" but exactly twice decoded so, "%ea%b0%80%ec%98%88%ea%b7%a0%ec%9d%bc%ea%b0%802000%ec%9b%90" is decoded to "가예균일가2000원" then decoded to "揶???域????2000??" again. finally it search with wrong query keyword "揶???域????2000??"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to encode query once again. Then I made

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(text.Text.Replace(' ', '+'))
```

to

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(text.Text.Replace(' ', '+')));
```

So, It works very well. Thank you for struggle to find solution. You don`t need to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me.  The text is encoded.

```
string text = "kim jong un";
string Encode = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(text.Replace(' ', '+'));

Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "http://www.homeplus.co.kr/app.search.HeaderSearch.ghs?comm=usr.header.search.basic4&search_query="
    + Encode + " --new-window";

process.Start();
```

Comment: When that site has alphabet query, It does not need to decode to search with that keyword. It only happen when search with Korean keyword